# Animate some divs only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate some divs after the user scrolls to a specific position on the page. the problem is that i want it to happen only once. I used Boolean flags but it doesn't seem to like it.

What are u all suggest me to do?

::**the code Its not even running**

FYI I don't want to use PHP

```
var once = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 760 && once == false) {
        $('.hash').each(function(i) {
            $(this).fadeOut(0).delay(1000 * i).fadeIn(1000);
        });
        once = true;
    }
)};
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're looping through every element with the 'hash' class, so the animation is going to fire for each one of these.

Comment: You can add a dummy css class and check it for occurence.

Comment: What about [`$.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)? Or look at [`$.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: The last line is wrong, change `)};` with `});`. The answer below solves your problem addition to this comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question

> after the user scrolls to a specific position on the page

Listen to `scroll` event

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     var once = false;
     $(document).on('scroll', function(){
       if ($(window).scrollTop() > 760 && once==false){
         $('.hash').each(function(i) {
           $(this).fadeOut(0).delay(1000*i).fadeIn(1000);
         });
         once=true;
       }
     });
   )};
```

Alternative from comments. Check if element has a class (or attribute) or not. Below code checks if the element has the `data-noanimate` attribute. If yes it will not animate, if not it will animate and add `data-noanimate` so that it will animate once.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $(document).on('scroll', function(){
       if ($(window).scrollTop() > 760){
         $('.hash').each(function(i) {
           if($(this).attr('data-noanimate') === undefined){
               $(this).attr('data-noanimate','true').fadeOut(0).delay(1000*i).fadeIn(1000);
           }
         });
       }
     });
   )};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var once=false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 760 &&once==false)
  {
    $('.hash').each(function(i) {
    $(this).fadeOut(0).delay(1000*i).fadeIn(1000);});
    once=true;
  }
});
```

Your brackets on the end of the ready function were flipped.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is correct, but it can be better like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 760) {
            $('.hash').each(function(i) {
                $(this).fadeOut(0).delay(1000 * i).fadeIn(1000);
            });
            // without boolean value,you can off `scroll` event
            $(window).off('scroll');
        }
    })
});
```