# Matplotlib, how to animate a simple lineplot only once

Tags: matplotlib, animation

I have a simple line plot that I would like to animate only once, not repeatedly as my current code does. I went through some solutions on Stackoverflow (e.g., [Animate some divs only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203458/animate-some-divs-only-once)), however they seemed daunting or too sophisticated. Is there a simple way to do it? Also, how can we increase the speed? Thank you in advance for your time.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': {0: 0,
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 3,
  4: 4,
  5: 5,
  6: 6,
  7: 7,
  8: 8,
  9: 9,
  10: 10,
  11: 11,
  12: 12,
  13: 13,
  14: 14,
  15: 15,
  16: 16,
  17: 17,
  18: 18,
  19: 19,
  20: 20,
  21: 21,
  22: 22,
  23: 23,
  24: 24,
  25: 25,
  26: 26,
  27: 27,
  28: 28,
  29: 29,
  30: 30,
  31: 31,
  32: 32,
  33: 33,
  34: 34,
  35: 35,
  36: 36,
  37: 37,
  38: 38,
  39: 39,
  40: 40,
  41: 41,
  42: 42,
  43: 43,
  44: 44,
  45: 45,
  46: 46,
  47: 47,
  48: 48,
  49: 49,
  50: 50},
 'y': {0: 0.7695,
  1: 0.7983,
  2: 0.7958,
  3: 0.7975,
  4: 0.7983,
  5: 0.7966,
  6: 0.7971,
  7: 0.7962,
  8: 0.7962,
  9: 0.7975,
  10: 0.7983,
  11: 0.7987,
  12: 0.7996,
  13: 0.7992,
  14: 0.7967,
  15: 0.7983,
  16: 0.7971,
  17: 0.7987,
  18: 0.7979,
  19: 0.7983,
  20: 0.7983,
  21: 0.7921,
  22: 0.7975,
  23: 0.7962,
  24: 0.7975,
  25: 0.7979,
  26: 0.7983,
  27: 0.7992,
  28: 0.7983,
  29: 0.7983,
  30: 0.7987,
  31: 0.7983,
  32: 0.7983,
  33: 0.7983,
  34: 0.7992,
  35: 0.7975,
  36: 0.7996,
  37: 0.7992,
  38: 0.7979,
  39: 0.7987,
  40: 0.7983,
  41: 0.7983,
  42: 0.7987,
  43: 0.7987,
  44: 0.7992,
  45: 0.7992,
  46: 0.7979,
  47: 0.7996,
  48: 0.7992,
  49: 0.7987,
  50: 0.7992}})


x = df['x']
y = df['y']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x, y, color='b')
def update(num, x, y, line):
    line.set_data(x[:num], y[:num])  
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, len(x), fargs=[x, y, line],
                              interval=15, blit=True)
ani.save('test.gif')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

To control the repetition, set `repeat=False`.

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, len(x), fargs=[x, y, line], interval=15, blit=True, repeat=False)
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for taking the time to try helping me. However, the proposed solution (repeat=False) is not working as the saved figure is still animated repeatedly.

Comment: I find [this comment & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111351/stop-gif-image-from-repeating-in-matplotlib) to be very helpful